# Unable to access Datalake with Service principal Access token from PostMan

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal

I have an Azure service principal with API permissions.

[image]

I am making an API call with it to get an access token. I am able to get the token but I cannot access datalake after I got that token. I set ACL permissions for this service principal at root container/dir/file level but still I cannot get the access.
I am getting the following error.[image]

```
    {
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationInfo",
        "message": "Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.\nRequestId:a08469ad-c01f-00dc-60c4-95a7d2000000\nTime:2022-07-12T07:55:28.3327947Z"
    }
}
```

[image]

Any suggestion to resolve this problem will be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results***

*I generated access token using **`v1.0 token endpoint`** same as you like below:*

***https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/token***

[image]

***When I use the above generated token to call the API, I too got the same error as below:***

[image]

***To resolve the error, you need to use `v2.0 token endpoint` like
below to generate the access token***:

***https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token***

[image]

***After using above generated token, I'm able to call the API successfully like below:***

[image]